# In-App SMS with pre-written body limited to 40 characters

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using the `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send a message within the application.

**Problem:**

When I send the text message to a non-iPhone (e.g. Nexus One), the message is always split into two or more text messages.

But if I sent the same message directly from the  native Messages app, the message is delivered in a single message.

And then I found this recently, Actually what is happening is the message body is splitting by 40 characters and I can not figure out the situation.

What could be wrong?  Is there a work around for this?

**CODE:**

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{

     controller.body = @"This is a sample body which is containing more than 40 characters...";
     controller.recipients = phnNumbersArray;
     controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
     [self.view presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
[controller release];
```

Comment: If the message body contains even only one Non-ASCII character, then MFMessageComposeViewController counts number of characters multiplied by 4.

So when message body reaches 40 characters, MFMessageComposeViewController counts it as 160. Since the one mobile message length is 160, it is dividing message into parts (after 40 character with non-ascii it is like 160 ascii characters, so it will charge for multiple messages by network provider too). 

So if you copy and paste message body from somewhere else, make sure they don't contain non-ASCII characters. That is what happened to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but possible three workaround for this.

1) Try using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myMsgBody];` I don't think it would work / resolves the issue, most probably. :P

2) See if you can send `NSUTF8StringEncoding` way.

3) Or the problem is at the carrier's side, nothing to do with your code.

Explanation: In your scenario I see the texts are breaking up into multiple texts. Servers at the carriers' site thinks your message is too long. That means too heavy to be sent at once. This basically means it's `xxmb` more than what the servers takes. To reduce that size i gave you the idea of encoding way...